# Most efficient way of keeping only the unique items in a list?

Tags: python, performance, list

So I'm relatively new to Python and trying to figure out what's the best way to keep only unique items in a list. My current implementation involves a Counter, dict and list comprehensions, but I'm not sure what may be faster.

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'a']
d = dict(Counter(l))
[key for key, val in d.items() if val == 1]
>>> ['b']
```

Also, this only works for strings and not ints and I'm not sure why.

Comment: The call to `dict` is superfluous: a `Counter` object has an `items` method. And what makes you think it doesn't work for integers?

Comment: Why not a set instead a list?

Comment: Hmm just tried it again and dunno why it didn't work for integers before. Oh, didn't know that Counter had an items method. And a set would keep the items that are not unique. In other words, I don't want 'a' in my answer.

Comment: Depends if the items are hashable or not

Comment: Why exactly don't you want 'a' in your answer? What are you going to do with the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want only things that exist one time?

```
>>> c=Counter(['a','b','a'])
>>> [n for n in c if c[n]==1]
['b']
>>> c=Counter([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,6])
>>> [n for n in c if c[n]==1]
[1, 4]
```

Or just a list of unique things?

```
>>> set([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,6])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 5):

Python has a built in type for ensuring that the members in a list are unique, it's a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set). Using your example:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'a']
set(l)
>>> ['a','b']
```

Commonly, you can "wash" the duplicate members from a list by converting from a list, to a set, and back again. For example:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'a']
list(set(l))
>>> ['a','b']
```

This will turn the list back into a mutable (editable) list and ensures the best combination of performance and convenience.

Comment: Note that this not preserve order.

Comment: This keeps elements that are not unique though. I don't want 'a' in my final list.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the way you were doing it. Though the dict is superflurous. This is quite efficient but will only work if the "keys" are all hashable

```
[k for k,v in Counter(L).iteritems() if v==1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate items, use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set), then re-convert the result to a list:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
unique = list(set(ls))
# unique is ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 'b']
```

Note that this operation won't preserve the order of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order, just use `set()`. However the following will preserve the order:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']

a = []
for item in l:
   if item not in a: a.append(item)
```

Or to only keep unique items:

```
l = [item for item in l if l.count(item) == 1]
```